# Returning JSON Data to JQGrid is prompting to save a file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I'm new to ASP.Net MVC. I'm trying a sample program to bind a JQGrid with data. When I return the JSON data from the Controller , the system is prompting me with a pop up "Do you want to Save the file ..".I beleive my browser is not able to understand JSON data. I went through the other post in StackOverFlow and none of them seem to help me. I'm running this on IE8 set to Compatibility mode. Please see the code below:

Index.cshtml

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
  }
  <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
   <link href="~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet"    type="text/css" />  
   <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
  <script src="~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myGrid").jqGrid({
        url: '../../Home/About/GetJQGridData',
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        myType: 'GET',
        colNames: ['Id', 'Name'],
        colModel: [
        { name: 'Id', index: 'Id' },
        { name: 'Name', index: 'Name' }
        ],
        jsonReader: {
            root: 'Data',
            id: 'id',
            repeatitems: false
        },
        pager: $('#myPager'),
        rowNum: 5,
        rowList: [2, 5, 10],
        width: 600,
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: 'Jqgrid MVC Tutorial'
        });
     });
   </script>



    <table id="myGrid"></table>  
     <div id="myPager"></div>`
```

My Controller code is as follows:

> HomeController.cs

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)] 
    public ActionResult GetJQGridData()
    {
        var jqGridData = new JQGridObject()
        {
            Data = GetSomeSampleData(),
            Page = "1",
            PageSize = 3, // u can change this !  
            SortColumn = "Name",
            SortOrder = "asc"
        };

        return Json(jqGridData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public List<Fruit> GetSomeSampleData()
    {
        return new List<Fruit>  
        {  
        new Fruit{Id = 1, Name = "Apple" },  
        new Fruit{Id = 2, Name = "Melon" },  
        new Fruit{Id = 3, Name = "Orange" },  
        new Fruit{Id = 4, Name = "Grapes" },  
        new Fruit{Id = 5, Name = "Pineapple" },  
        new Fruit{Id = 6, Name = "Mango" },  
        new Fruit{Id = 7, Name = "Bannana" },  
        new Fruit{Id = 8, Name = "Cherry" }  
        };
    }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing that jumps out at me is that your Controller/View is being referenced incorrectly

```
url: '../../Home/About/GetJQGridData',
```

should be

```
url: '/Home/GetJQGridData',
```

You shouldn't need to set a jsonReader as well on the client.

Comment: That was the issue. Thanks Mark.